# Do I need 2 normal maps to solve this issue?

Tags: normal-map

I want my character to flex his Bicep, when he does, veins should show up, but only when activated.

The problem I have is the normal map is already used for all the other details of my character.  If I put the veins in, they'll be static.

Is there a way I can clip the veins on ONLY when he flexes?  How would I approach this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a BW mask the turn normals on/off locally.
Use the *Strength* input of the *Normal Map* node.

Then just animate the BW mask.

[image]

Comment: Hello to the downvoter :). I'd appreciate some feedback on what can be improved on this answer. I'm fine with the downvote, just want to learn :).